# Most efficient way to detect non-transparent pixels in ImageMagick / RMagick

Tags: ruby, numpy, imagemagick, heatmap, rmagick

I've got a series of drawings created via HTML Canvas. I need to create a heatmap using these drawings to show where the most common areas are.

Each drawing is a PNG image with a transparent background. The only non-transparent pixels are those which the users has drawn on. Here are a couple sample images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZwHx.jpg

I'm looking for the most efficient way to grab the non-transparent pixels for each image, which I will then add to a matrix to generate a heatmap.

I can get this by iterating over each pixel and checking it's alpha value. However, these images are roughly 1400 x 750 pixels each, so that's ~1,000,000 of checks per image. This becomes untenable when we have hundreds of images to analyze on the fly.

Is there any way to do this more efficiently? I'm open to all ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In command line ImageMagick, you can list all the non-transparent pixels using sparse-color: or parsing txt:. Here is a 100x100 transparent image with a 2x2 red square in the top left corner.

[image]

```
convert img.png sparse-color:
```

```
0,0,srgba(255,0,0,1) 1,0,srgba(255,0,0,1) 0,1,srgba(255,0,0,1) 1,1,srgba(255,0,0,1)
```

or

```
convert x.png txt: | tail -n +2 | grep -v "none" | awk '{print $1 $4}'
```

```
0,0:red
1,0:red
0,1:red
1,1:red
```

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, I do not know the RMagick equivalent.